# adding columns in numpy - still confused

Tags: arrays, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I know there have been plenty of questions asked and answered concerning columns in `NumPy`, but I'm still stuck. Unfortunately, `np.append` isn't working for me as it says that there is no module.

I'm working with the `boston` dataset which has the median values stored separately from the main `boston.data` (shape is (506, 13) as `boston.target` (shape is (506, 1)). I want to make it so that the `boston.target` feature (aka the column) is added to the `boston.data` so that it's shape is (506, 14), with `boston.data`[13] being the `boston.target` data.

My attempt, based on other suggestions I've seen has been:

```
np.append(boston.data, boston.target, axis=0)
print boston.data.shape
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Doing just `np.append(boston.data, boston.target)`gives me nothingl it returns the same `boston.data`, or at least as far as I can tell.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The whole code, if anyone has `ipython` open, is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()

print boston.data.shape
print boston.target.shape
copyarr = np.append(boston.data, boston.target, axis=1) #changed still runs error
print copyarr.shape

at --> copyarr = np.append(boston.data, boston.target, axis=1)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should set axis=1, not 0.
You are attempting to add a column, not row. That is why numpy is giving the error about the different number of dimensions for the arrays.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.append(boston.data, boston.target.reshape(-1, 1), axis=1)
```

Another way to add a column is to use hstack.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.hstack((boston.data, boston.target.reshape(-1, 1)))
```

The cause of your problem is that boston.target has shape (506,). It is a 1D array whereas `boston.data` has shape (506, 13), which is a 2D array. You need to reshape `boston.target` explicitly to have shape (506, 1) using `boston.target.reshape(-1, 1)` where the -1 means infer the number of rows so that the data is reshaped into 1 column.

Also note that in both cases, a copy of the array is made i.e. the array boston.data is not modified in place. This means the result of appending the column should be stored in another variable as shown above.

Comment: so I would have to assign a new array to hold the copy? ex. copyarray = np.hstack((boston.data, boston.target)) either way, that is still giving me an error, this time: ValueError: all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions

Comment: I've edited my answer. Your array `boston.target` does not have shape (506, 1). It has shape (506,), which is different.